# coercion and identity with constraints in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a reason why `coerce` does not have a default for the identity with respect to constraints ?

```hs
import Data.Coerce
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

newtype Id a = Id a

a :: Id Int
a = coerce 3 -- bad

-- • Couldn't match representation of type ‘a0’ with that of ‘Int’ arising from a use of ‘coerce’
-- • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘3’
--   prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
--   Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
--   These potential instances exist:
--     instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
--     instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
--     instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’

b :: Id Int
b = coerce (3 :: Int)
```

I imagined that it could attempt to solve that with `a0 ~ Int` (or other constraints in general), as the identity (and merging contraints) seems always an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think the answer is probably the boring one: nobody has had both the idea and the time to do the engineering work needed to add that special case to the type checker. I don't see a technical reason not to do it, and if you emitted a warning each time such defaulting was done (or hid it behind a language extension, or both) I think it's reasonably likely GHC HQ would accept such a patch.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if I had a wrong picture of what's going on. This seems like a good project. Not sure I can do it, I should post it to GHC's gitlab in case someone is interested to pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is inherently ambiguous

```
a :: Id Int
a = coerce 3
```

because it actually means

```
a :: Id Int
a = coerce (fromInteger (3 :: Integer))
```

and here `fromInteger` could return *any* type `T` in class `Num`, as long as `T` can be converted to `Id Int` by `coerce`.

One possible solution is, of course, `T ~ Int`, but it's not the only one. Consider this contrived example:

```
newtype T = T Int

instance Num T where
   fromInteger n = T (fromInteger n + 1)

a :: Id Int
a = coerce (3 :: T)
-- which means  a = coerce (fromInteger (3 :: Integer) :: T)
```

Here, we have `a = Id 4` because `fromInteger` incremented the `Int`, which differs from the `Id 3` we would get from `a = coerce (3 :: Int)`.

When performing type inference on `coerce 3`, Haskell can not know if we mean `coerce (3 :: Int)` or `coerce (3 :: T)`, so the code is inherently ambiguous, and rejected as such.

Comment: @DanielWagner That would be a special case: we would resolve `Coercible` constraints unlike others. We already have "special" classes (numeric defaults), do we need more? What if the programmer intended to use `coerce (3 :: T)` but forgot the `::T`? What if we have `Coercible a X, Coercible b Y, Coercible a b`, with `X` coercible to `Y`; do we get `a~b~X` or `a~b~Y`? Perhaps in this case the magic should not trigger, and an ambiguity error should still be generated. I am not strongly against magic, but I _am_ somehow afraid of unpredictable magic.

Comment: *unpredictable* magic is the worse for sure and defaults are dangerous. (I did not have the distinction between `Int` and `Integer` in mind, for instance). I can imagine that a "retry upon failure" based solution could trigger some unforeseen loops (?). that said coercible is in the trusted codebase.  the problem can be framed (I think) in a way beyond `Coercible` : if we see those type classes (and types..) as a logical system, it's really about quotienting some relations by some others.

Comment: nb : I imagine we would get the reflexive transitive closure of all those relations. that's, I think, a way to quotient without actual quotient classes, by saturating the relations on the various elements of the same class. it might be how its implemented. I think `Typeable` generates a lots of those constraints